# Redirect top page after actions within iframe have concluded

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a modal by bootstrap, and in that modal I created an iframe.
From the inside of the iframe I show a web page, which will lead to another web page, and from the final web page inside iframe, I wish to redirect top page to another url.

```js
echo '    <script type="text/javascript">',
'document.getElementById("link").click();',
'</script>';



echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
'top.location== "https://www.google.com";',
'redi();',
'</script>'
;
```

```html
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalgoogle" name="myModalgoogle">
            <div class="modal-dialog ">
                <div class="modal-content">


                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <iframe src="openidgoo/join/CGODI456923CDMXDNV40L555" style="height:650px;width:450px; border: none;" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: There must be no interaction between main window and an iframe. If you need to redirect user when modal opens, then implement `<a>` tag, if you still need to redirect when user clicks on link in iframe, then you have to implement the DOM within your main window. not in iframe

Comment: Your question is unclear and really hard to understand. Can you please rephrase it better so that users will be able to answer you easier ?

Comment: Clarified the intent that is wished to be achieved.